# bootstrap 4 responsive table

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hey i've got the following problem when i am trying to use the bootsrap 4 responsive table.

If there isnt evenough in the table to fill the complete width its look like this.

[Layout of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jDKH.png)
[image]

My code is the following:

```html
<div class="container" id="maincontainer">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Bevorstehende Veranstaltungen:</p>
    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>

<p>Vergangene Veranstaltungen:</p>
    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Username</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">30.06.2017 15:30 - 16:00</th>
      <td>2/2</td>
      <td>dafdfsfa</td>
      <td>97</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I hope anyone can help me.

Best Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have 2 separate tables with 2 different lengths of text in the first column. The only way I can think to make the first columns exactly the same width is to have the exact same amount of characters in them, i.e. add a date and time stamp to the first table.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap table, the width of the column will be depends on the data.

If you want columns on both table as same width, I think the `<div>` may be useful instead of `Table`.

```
<p>Bevorstehende Veranstaltungen:</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <b>#</b> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <b> First Name</b> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <b>  Last Name</b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <b>Username</b> 
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<p>Bevorstehende Veranstaltungen:</p>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <b>#</b>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <b> First Name</b>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
     <b>  Last Name</b>
   </div>
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <b>Username</b>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row primary-bordered-table">
  <div class="col-md-3">
      30.06.2017 15:30 - 16:00
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
      2/2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
      dafdfsfa
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
      97
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the column will be like in the following image

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to make it just The Same width if there isnt enough chars to Fill The Full width?

Comment: `<div>` tag can't depend the number of charactors. So I think it is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

You can set width in js also, give same width 
like

```
$('.table').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "30%" },
    { "width": "20%" },
    { "width": "20%" },
    { "width": "30%" },
  ]
} )
```